# check if a particular property in a class (not an instance of class) exist

Tags: iphone, ios, nsobject

i have to create a class method and i need to check if a particular string correspond to a property in a class.

example:

```
@interface aClass
@property (nonatomic, strong) aType *property1;
@end
```

in other class:

```
+ (X*)createXwithProperty:(NSString*) aProperty
{
  if([aClass haveProperty:aProperty])
    {
       return create(X);
    }
  else return nil;
}
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a @propery it has getter and setter method.

In your example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) aType *property1;
```

Getter method should be called `property1` as your property, so you can check if your class instance responds to that selector like this:

Convert NSString to selector:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"property1");
if ([aClassInstance respondsToSelector:selector]) {
   NSLog(@"RESPONDS");
}
```

Sorry, I was to fast on answering. I see now that you want to check if class has specific property, but you don't have a class instance.
To see if class has specific property use this (basically, the principle it is the same as with class instances :) ):

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"property1");
if ([aClassNotInstance instancesRespondToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"RESPONDS");
}
```

Comment: now i want to use the same validation mechanism to check a property in NSManagedObject, the problem is that this can't be done (see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053974/nsfetchrequest-returning-nothing) the solution is to create an NSEntityDescription, there's no other solution without instantiating any class?